# What's the tAtparya of न वै योषा कंचन हिनस्ति in Shatapatha Brahmana?

Tags: women, shatapatha-brahmana

**न वै योषा कंचन हिनस्ति** appears in SB 6.3.1.39
The weapon/spade is personified as a female and these lines are spoken to it. What's the tAtparya behind such a reference?

Comment: Many of the divine weapons are sentient/people.